# Call to a member function setCondition() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

When I update the entity class data, it throws

> Error: Call to a member function setCondition() on a non-object

I want to set the "condition" True.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$result = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:UserStats')->find(1002);

$result->setCondition(TRUE); // want to set the codition from False to TRUE
$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your find method is returning something like `FALSE` or `NULL`.  You need to determine what your find methods returns when it can't find the entity by that ID and check against it before trying to use that entity.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$result = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:UserStats')->find(1002);

if( isset($result) && $result !== false ) {
    $result->setCondition(TRUE); // want to set the codition from False to TRUE
}
$em->flush();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, do you know if i want to find "personPhoneNumber" from my entity class, how should i get it, using findBypersonPhoneNumber(1002)  OR find('personPhoneNumbe', '1002') !

Comment: I'm not a symphony guy, unfortunately, so not sure how your repository works.  It should be easy to find in the docs though as searching by other fields is a mandatory feature for any kind of repository system.